# tomcat7 keeps saying it's running, application not working (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat7, raspberry-pi

So to explain everything...

I had a perfectly working instance of tomcat7 working with an application in one of my directories. There were no problems.

I then switched it to wifi rather than the ethernet, and it stopped working. So I fixed my networking issue (set a static wifi ip), and tried but it still wouldn't work. Switched it back to ethernet and it didn't go back. So I went and sudo `rm -r my-apache-folder` and tried to reinstall. Nothing. Decided to then use apt-get to install tomcat7 and still nothing. Before it was due to `JRE_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` not being set, and that might still be a problem but tomcat says it's running when it definitely isn't.

I don't want to flood you with server.xml or something like that until I'm asked to, so please help me and I'll respond efficiently, been working on this small problem for a week or 2 now, been using every aid on the internet to no avail.

port 8080 isn't running tomcat:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/$ sudo netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State            PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN          15286/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2334/vsftpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2293/sshd
```

Tomcat7 is "running":

```
pi@raspberrypi:/$ sudo service tomcat7 restart
[ ok ] Stopping Tomcat servlet engine: tomcat7.
[ ok ] Starting Tomcat servlet engine: tomcat7.
```

My java directories set in `/etc/environment`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/tomcat7$ $JRE_HOME
-bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-armhf/: Is a directory
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/tomcat7$ $JAVA_HOME
-bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-armhf/jre/: Is a directory
```

when i ran `ps -ef|grep catalina`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/tomcat7$ ps -ef|grep catalina
pi       28778  2542  0 22:36 pts/0    00:00:00 grep catalina
```

last 26 lines of 'catalina.out':

```
04-Mar-2015 21:58:47 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 57199 ms
04-Mar-2015 21:58:47 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:353)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:336)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:703)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
04-Mar-2015 21:58:47 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
04-Mar-2015 21:58:49 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
04-Mar-2015 21:58:50 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
04-Mar-2015 21:58:52 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0     ip6-localnet
ff00::0     ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1   raspberrypi
```

Comment: Did you forget to configure firewall / NAT / port forwarding?

Comment: nope, I have ports 80, 22, and 8080 for this ip forwarded on my router

Comment: What does `ps -ef|grep catalina` give you? Did you take a look at `TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out`?

Comment: I updated the question with the ps result, but catalina.out is past the char limit on here. is there another way of posting?

Comment: Just look at the errors at the bottom of the file. They should give a hint what went wrong during startup.

Comment: updated: last 26 lines of catalina.out added

Comment: Does your `/etc/hosts` file contain the line `127.0.0.1   localhost`?

Comment: yup `127.0.0.1` is localhost and `127.0.1.1` at the bottom with name `raspberrypi`

Comment: Probably a problem with your loopback interface. Are you able to ping `127.0.0.1` and/or `localhost`?

Comment: i get `5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4008ms` so definitely not receiving anything.

Comment: Could you disable `iptables` and try again?

Comment: it said iptables wasn't recognized as a service (`service iptables stop`)

Comment: Try `/etc/init.d/iptables stop` instead (you must be root) - (FYI iptables isn't a service)

Comment: If that doesn't help take a look at your loopback if config -> see here for details http://linux.about.com/od/lna_guide/a/gdelna47t00.htm

Comment: there's no iptables in init.d, checking your link now....localhost works now.

Comment: Ok my bad - was just blindly guessing the path without knowing your exact OS. For raspbian it could be under `/sbin/iptables`. However, by default it might not be enabled anyways... (but as i said im just guessing)

Comment: correction: `ping localhost` works now. `/sbin/iptables stop` doesn't work though

Comment: So for whatever reason, tomcat7's splash page/manager pages have started working, but it still isn't enabling for the webpage I made.

Comment: Great :) - have a look at the log-files. It should tell you what went wrong during deployment.

Comment: alrighty i'll probably check it out tomorrow and get back to you

Comment: so when I tried to startup the tomcat instance (tomcat as a servlet works) I got this

`pi@raspberrypi:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin$ ./startup.sh
Cannot find /var/www/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/bin/setclasspath.sh
This file is needed to run this program`

I had a previous instance that I got rid of, but it looks like it's linking there instead. help about re-referencing where it looks for setclasspath? it's in the same directory I ran startup.sh in

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I "started from the bottom, now I'm here". haha I took the application and tested it on a separate computer, got it to work again, brought it back to the server, and got it back to where it was when I had this problem. In this case, however, I KNOW tomcat7 is running, and I can access the page. Now I feel that the issue of inactivity is most likely a problem with the address and how it's posted.

I'll update until it's solved!

NEW Catalina.out

```
8-Mar-2015 20:10:19 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina initDirs
SEVERE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
08-Mar-2015 20:10:20 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/server.xml]
08-Mar-2015 20:10:20 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina initDirs
SEVERE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
08-Mar-2015 20:10:20 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/server.xml]
08-Mar-2015 20:10:20 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

update: fixed the above configuration issue, so it seems like I have everything working but the actual site. I have the correct IP and the correct port, meaning its a problem with the configuration. I tried using a non apt-get install (used a binary distro) and runs fine just like the apt-get package, but not working for my page. it goes to the "it works!" page on 8080, then I put a socket to listen to port 8080 and it doesn't respond. I check my router and everything is fine. This is driving me crazy.

update: port 8080 is closed externally but functions fine internally, most likely a problem with tomcat configuration/security